# Where and when should I structure my view-specfic Javascript into files in my Asp.net mvc application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.Net Mvc application that contains a good deal of javascript in a lot of different views (I know, I've dreaded this moment up until now).

For instance, I use Google maps in several views, and the way I do it today is initizalize each map whenever it's view is rendered.

I find this to be a cumbersome task and it makes my views look really messy. Is there such a thing as "best practice" or a correct way of structuring these things?
Wouldn't simply including the javascript-file in the master layout cause the script to render every time, even though I don't need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/). When a view (i.e. your google maps view) is rendered, a small piece of JS is executed to asynchronously load a script. Once that script is loaded, you can then call a function to init your google map.

It's 'kind of' IoC for scripts...